# Command ps freezed. How to fix it?

Tags: 12.04, vmware

When I execute ps on the server runs ubuntu 12.04, it always freeze.

like this:

```
root@xxx:xxxxx# ps

  PID TTY          TIME CMD

26328 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo

26329 pts/1    00:00:00 su

26330 pts/1    00:00:00 bash

Signal 11 (SEGV) caught by ps (procps version 3.2.8)

Please send bug reports
```

And, this makes high load average as standing process.

This error have never happens until I add many users that I must add.

I searched on google many times, but I can't find how to fix it.

Could you tell me the solution?

Sorry for my dirty English.

P.S.:

I run this machine on vmware esxi 5.1.

And, It is created by Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" Minimal CD.

on this page

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Does it have connection with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is  a bug on linux kernel, you can see at this document

- http://debian.2.n7.nabble.com/Bug-702965-procps-ps-dies-with-SIGSEGV-on-kernels-gt-3-2-29-and-lots-of-supplementary-groups-td2890061.html
- http://forums.grsecurity.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3298
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/procps/+bug/639798

but this is old bug on Ubuntu, i don't know it is still exist on newer kernel..

Comment: you're welcome, to solve this problem you must patch it with patch